# Yandex maps - автобусы онлайн

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как создать автобусы онлайн через апи?
Используется параметр `masstransit`, но как его прикрутить коду API?
В песочнице Yandex API-map, общественного транспорта нет.
Есть построение маршрутов, но мне нужно простое передвижение общественного транспорта.
Покажите куда читать? И где код подсмотреть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Отображение общественного транспорта в режиме реального времени - это возможности сервиса Я.Транспорт, а не Яндекс.Карт. К сожалению, у Я.Транспорта нет API.

Comment: И даже через frame ни как? Я пытался через фрейм, но добился лишь обычную карту.

Comment: нет, виджет с карт не поддерживает эту возможность.